# delete redundant rows in a dataframe with set in columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
Cluster OsId    BrowserId   PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred
0   11  11  {789615, 955761, 1149586, 955764, 955767, 1187...   147.0   71.0
1   0   11  12  {1184903, 955761, 1149586, 1158132, 955764, 10...   73.0    38.0
2   0   11  15  {1184903, 1109643, 955761, 955764, 1074581, 95...   72.0    40.0
3   0   11  16  {1123200, 1184903, 1109643, 1018637, 1005581, ...   7815.0  5077.0
4   0   11  17  {1184903, 789615, 1016529, 955761, 955764, 955...   52.0    47.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
307 {0, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21}    99  16  1154705 220.0   182.0
308 {18}    99  16  1155314 12.0    6.0
309 {9} 99  16  1158132 4.0 4.0
310 {0, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21}    99  16  1184903 966.0   539.0
```

This dataframe contains redundansts rows that I need to delete them , so I try this :

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

But I got this error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`

Any idea to help me to fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `frozenset`s for avoid `unhashable set`s type with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with invert mask by `~`:

```
#sets are in any column
df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: frozenset(x) if isinstance(x, set) else x)
df[~df1.duplicated()]
```

If no row was removed it means no row has duplicates (tested are all columns together)

Comment: I get this error too : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @user17241 - what column has sets?

Comment: all these columns : Cluster ,OsId ,   BrowserId ,  PageId

Comment: @user17241 - are you sure ? Is sample seems only one column, all another are integers and flaots

Comment: @user17241 - what return `df.columns[df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, set))]` ?

Comment: Index(['PageId'], dtype='object')

Comment: @user17241 - hmmm, so it means there is combinations? Some values in column `PageId` has no sets? Answer was edited.

Comment: sorry but same error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: @user17241 - what is `df.iloc[0].to_dict()` ?

Comment: {'Cluster': 0,
 'OsId': 11,
 'BrowserId': 11,
 'PageId': {789615, 955761, 955764, 955767, 1149586, 1187774},
 'VolumePred': 147.0,
 'ConversionPred': 71.0}

Comment: @user17241 - how working now edited answer?

Comment: It is a combination between columns: when a column is a set, the other no and vive versa